# Azure Load Balancer to balance the load between multiple ports but in same VM (Backend Pool)

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I have having a hard time find a solution for this.

I have an `Azure` **Internal** Load Balancer (level 4). And I have **ONLY** one Virtual Machine act as the `backend pool` for the said Load Balancer.

And fun part starts here, I have multiple `Docker` containers running on that Virtual Machine. Running Nginx Web servers on ports `8080` and `8081`.

And now I want to balance the load between these two ports.  Literally what I want is something like below in the photo:

[image]

So according to the photo, the request comes from `abc.xyz.com` and it should hit the Load Balancer, and then it should route the traffic to the only VM running multiple docker containers in multiple ports.

How can I achieve this behavior?

I have already setup `A frontend configuration with private ip`, `a rule`, `backend pool`

Comment: Hello @Jananath. if my answer was helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per this article(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts#unsupported-networking-scenarios), placing an Azure Load Balancer in front of container instances in a networked container group is not supported and similarly it is not possible to route the traffic on containers to their specific ports running on a single Virtual Machine. The above solution works on VM level not on container level.

The only workaround for this scenario would be to use Azure Application gateway as Microservice architecture is supported on App gateway. To probe on different ports, you need to configure multiple HTTP settings. Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#can-one-backend-pool-serve-many-applications-on-different-ports

Azure Application Gateway is a web traffic load balancer that enables you to manage traffic to your web applications. And you can create an internal application gateway. To do that you can create an Application Gateway with both public and private frontend IP address and do not create any listeners for the public frontend IP address. Application Gateway will not listen to any traffic on the public IP address if no listeners are created for it.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-front-end-ip ,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#how-do-i-use-application-gateway-v2-with-only-private-frontend-ip-address

Comment: But the problem is I tried many scenarios even with multiple HTTP settings. What I want to do is, when I hit `abc.example.com` it should load balance that request on `multiple port` on the same `vm`. How can I achieve this? I tried combinations of multiple `http settings`,  multiple `rules`, multiple `listeners` but neither of them worked.

Comment: Hitting a fqdn and load balancing that traffic on different ports is not possible. However, you can serve traffic on different ports using Azure App gateway as mentioned

Comment: Hi Rahul do you have proof where it says "Hitting a fqdn and load balancing that traffic on different ports is not possible"

Comment: A load-balancing rule maps a given frontend IP configuration and port to multiple backend IP addresses and ports. And that is how load balancing works. Each rule must produce a flow with a unique combination of destination IP address and destination port. There are two types of rules: 1. The default rule with no backend port reuse 2. The Floating IP rule where backend ports are reused.
Refer rule : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-multivip-overview

Comment: If you need to deliver flows to the same DIP on different ports, you need to use multiple frontend IPs. However, you need to keep in mind the backend pool management of LB: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/backend-pool-management
 Overall ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-multiple-ip